# pyttsx3 save_to_file() stops at a period

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx3

Im trying to write a test program for TTS inorder to use it in my main project. When i use the savetofile command, it only outputs up to the first period.

for example:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
hell = "this is period 1. this is period 2"
engine.setProperty('voice', 'com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.alex')
engine.save_to_file(hell, 'test.mp3')
engine.runAndWait()
```

exports a file called test.mp3 that says "this is period 1."
how do I make it say the next sentance?

Comment: I have a similar issue when i used it multiple times only the end gets save or nothing at all. What backend are u using?